# How to Authenticate Scopes From a Google Apps Script Library?

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently I have a google apps script library that is accessing the scopes of

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
```

Which includes an Advanced Google Service of the People API. The Problem I run into, is when I add the library to another script, it is giving me the error
`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.contactGroups.list failed with error: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

Steps I have tried:

- I tried adding the OathScopes to appscript.json in the library, but the script importing the library didn't inherit all the scopes.
- Currently I am manually putting in the oathScopes into every new script that imports the library, but for scalability this isn't a great option.

Solutions I have searched for hours, maybe I'm just asking the wrong questions, include:

- Is there a way to check for the scopes the current user has via script and force a request for access if they don't have them all?
- Is there a way to have my scripts inherit the permissions of a library?

Comment: In your situation, how about removing `oauthScopes` at the client side which is installing the library with `oauthScopes`? By this, the client side uses the scopes of the library. And, when the other method for using other scopes at the library side is added, when the client side runs the function, the authorization process is run for authorizing new scope. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Let me test again, I tried that before, and it didn't ask for all the scopes that the library required, which is why I found and added OathScopes.

Comment: In my sanitized environment it appears to work just fine. I wonder why that issue is occurring in my project. The reason I ran through all these hoops was because I got that error before adding OathScopes to any project.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.